# How to point primary domain to subdir and remove subdirectory from URL with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

My primary domain on my webhosting I am having point to a subdirectory within public_html via htaccess like so:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /apt/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^apt/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule !^apt/ apt%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

However, within that subdirectory, all URLs include the subdirectory (which is the domain). So it's domain.com/domain.com/page. Locally I use AMPPS and so the URLs are localhost/domain.com/page. Something I should fix...

How do I remove the subdirectory from URL paths? Do I do so in the htaccess within the subdirectory?  Thanks.

UPDATE: Now after plenty of messing around, the root htaccess has:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-web.agency$
RewriteRule !^my-web.agency/ my-web.agency/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

URLs work with and without the subdirectory in URL; however I want to disallow the subdirectory from the URI.

Also every link auto-generated by ProcessWire includes the subdir in URI.

Inside the subdir my-web.agency is a ProcessWire install (think WordPress for this case) with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteRule "(^|/)\.(?!well-known)" - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^|/)site-[^/]+/install/[^/]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)\.htaccess$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/assets/(cache|logs|backups|sessions|config|install|tmp)($|/.*$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/install($|/.*$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/assets.*/-.+/.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(wire|site|site-[^/]+)/(config|index\.config|config-dev)\.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(wire|site|site-[^/]+)/templates-admin($|/|/.*\.(php|html?|tpl|inc))$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/templates($|/|/.*\.(php|html?|tpl|inc))$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/assets($|/|/.*\.php)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)wire/(core|modules)/.*\.(php|inc|tpl|module|info\.json)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/modules/.*\.(php|inc|tpl|module|info\.json)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(COPYRIGHT|INSTALL|README|htaccess)\.(txt|md|textile)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)site-default/
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/~?[-_.a-zA-Z0-9/]*$"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How do I remove the subdirectory from the URL? Please?

Comment: @ linens did you get any solution for that?

Comment: no solution after these years?